# Run test with coverage failed in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-testing, test-coverage

I right clicked on my LoginActivityTest file and select **Run LoginActivityTest**, it ran and completed all the tests.

Now I want to run it with coverage. I then right clicked on the LoginActivityTest file and select **Run LoginActivityTest with Coverage**, it took sometime to build it, and then spits out the following:

```
---- IntelliJ IDEA coverage runner ---- 
sampling ...
include patterns:
com\.example\.ui\.login\..*
exclude patterns:
Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "com.example.ui.login.LoginActivityTest"Empty test suite.
```

Anyone has this same issue? Am I missing something? How can I get it to run with test coverage?